# Compilation error in Java code (cannot find symbol)

Tags: java

I've changed my code quite a bit.  I apologize for not being more clear before.  I need to find the sum of ints at the odd index positions within an array.  I've modified my code to this:

```
  public class OddIndex 
   {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        OddIndex arr = new OddIndex();
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++) 
         {
           if ((i%2!=0))
            {
              sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numbers.length));              
            }
         }

         System.out.println(sum);
       }
     }
```

The output should be 30, but I'm receiving 50.  Not sure where the error exists within the code.

***EDIT***

I've fixed it myself after all.  See below for answer.  I appreciate the input from everyone!

Comment: Line 11 is a `{`.  Is this really the source code?

Comment: Please add proper code to get a senseful response.

Comment: What is OddArray and do you have any imports at the top (or basically what line exactly)?

Comment: Synthesizing the `OddArray` in, I'm not able to notice any compilation errors from what you've shown us.  You need to include the imports and the *full* compilation failure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use oddarray. 
First of all you haven't even imported oddArray. You cannot use it.
Your question is really confusing. Im assuming you want to know which elements in your array are odd and then their sum.

```
    public class OddArrayClient
    {
     public static void main( String[] args)
     {

       int [] intEle = {25, 2, 6, 86, 2, 9};

       int sum=0;
       System.out.print( "The odd elements of the array are: " );


       for (int i = 0; i < intEle.length; i++)
       {

         if (intEle[i]%2 !=0)
         {
         System.out.print(intEle[i] + " ");
         sum=sum+intEle[i];        
         }
       }


      System.out.println();

      System.out.println("The product of all odd elements is: "+sum);  
 }
```

}

Comment: I've modified my entry.  I apologize for not being more clear before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not yet defined or imported OddArray

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OddArrayClient
{
  public static void main( String [] args )
   {
    int [] sampleArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    int sum=0;


    for ( int i = 0; i < sampleArray.length; i++ )
    {
      if (i%2 != 0)
      {
        sum=sum+sampleArray[i];
      }
    }

    System.out.print( "The sum of odd elements of the array is : " +sum);
   }
}
```